# Using HtmlAgilityPack with C# to find all href links within td elements in html page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, html-agility-pack

I am attempting to use HtmlAgilityPack package to find each of the href links within td tags throughout an entire html page. The trick is that these tables start deep down into the html structure. I noticed with HtmlAgilityPack you can't just say get all tds that are within trs on a page. There is a parent div wrapped around each table with a class on it "table-group" that I am not showing in my sample below. Maybe I can use that as a starting point? The biggest trouble that I am dealing with is that there are several parent elements above everything in my sample below, but I want to skip all of that and start here.

Here is a sample of the structure I am trying to navigate:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="https://path-to-pdf1" target="_blank">Link 1</a></td>
            <td><a href="https://path-to-pdf1" target="_blank">1</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="https://path-to-pdf2" target="_blank">Link 2</a></td>
            <td><a href="https://path-to-pdf2" target="_blank">2</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="https://path-to-pdf3" target="_blank">Link 3</a></td>
            <td><a href="https://path-to-pdf3" target="_blank">3</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="https://path-to-pdf4" target="_blank">Link 4</a></td>
            <td><a href="https://path-to-pdf4" target="_blank">4</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="https://path-to-pdf5" target="_blank">Link 5</a></td>
            <td><a href="https://path-to-pdf5" target="_blank">5</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="https://path-to-pdf6" target="_blank">Link 6</a></td>
            <td><a href="https://path-to-pdf6" target="_blank">6</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like my end result to be:
https://path-to-pdf1
https://path-to-pdf2
https://path-to-pdf3
https://path-to-pdf4
https://path-to-pdf5
https://path-to-pdf6

Here is what I have tried:

```
var html = @"https://myurl.com";

HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);

var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody/tr/td/a[0]");

    foreach (var item in nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Attributes["href"].Value);
    }

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify

`var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody/tr/td/a[0]");`

to

```
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a");
```

then you wil  get the result you want ,you could read the documents related with XPath for more details

I tried in a MVC project with the same html file:

[image]

Update:

I copied the html codes to the html page in my local and get the nodes successfully

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, but I think my problem still exists because on the actual html page the tables are deeper in the html structure not at the root level like in my example. Shouldn't this code just go down as far as it needs to until it finds a table? It seems like it is not.

Comment: "/ " Selection starts from the root node and  "//" Selection starts from the current node that match the selection

Comment: Your codeswill  go down as far as it needs to until it finds all tables, Also,For example,if you try with "//table//td[1]/a" you would also get the result you want

Comment: If  it does not perform as expected,please show the minimal codes that could reproduce the error

Comment: Thank you guys. This is the html page I am trying to get the pdf urls from. https://www.duke-energy.com/home/billing/rates/electric-tariff?jur=OH01. I am currently using //table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a and it is not skipping down to the //table for some reason. I am getting a null pointer.

Comment: Have you tried to copy the html codes to local and try again? I tried and get the nodes successfully,it may not the issue with the XPath